# For loop function too few arguments to function

Tags: c, error-handling

Hi I'm somewhat very new to programming and I just came across this new error called "too few arguments to function" and have no idea what this means. I've been trying to figure out for a while whats exactly wrong with the code, but I'm having no luck so far. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

```
int sumRange(int lowerNumber, int higherNumber);

int main()
{
   int lowerNumber,
       higherNumber,
       sum;

   scanf("%d%d", lowerNumber, higherNumber);

   printf("\nThe smaller number is %d and the larger number is %d", lowerNumber,higherNumber);
   printf("\nThe sum number of all ranges for both numbers is: %d", sumRange(sum));
}
int sumRange(int lowerNumber, int higherNumber)
{
   int x,
       total;

   for(x = lowerNumber; x <= higherNumber; x++)
   {
      total = total + x;
   }

 return x;
}
```

Comment: Examine the call to `sumRange` carefully. What does it take? What should it take?

Comment: Please don't edit the code in real time in response to comments. Just post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: For the record, `scanf("%d%d", lowerNumber, higherNumber);` is incorrect, it should be `scanf("%d%d", &lowerNumber, &higherNumber);` and another fault was answered by @RodrigoDeOliveiraSiqueira.

Answer (score 1):

Function main() lacks initial { and final }.
Also, in function sumRange, you may want to return total, not the x.

Also, in line "printf("\nThe sum number of all ranges for both numbers is: %d", sumRange(sum));"
you are calling sumRange with only one parameter. You should call it with two parameters: sumRange(lowerNumber,higherNumber)

Comment: Okay, I did some corrections to the code and I'm still getting that same error "too few arguments" when compiling

Comment: Please post the exact error message, although we won't know which line it is on because you didn't post the whole code - or maybe you did but failed to `#include` any library headers. @EugeneSh. has commented the problem.

Comment: @PaulDann probably has something to do with `int sumRange(int lowerNumber, int higherNumber);` and `sumRange(sum)`. As Eugene mentioned initially

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the "total".

```
    int sumRange(int lowerNumber, int higherNumber)
{
   int x,
       total;

   total = 0;
   for(x = lowerNumber; x <= higherNumber; x++)
   {
      total = total + x;
   }

 return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just came across this new error called "too few arguments to function" and have no idea what this means

It means that the function wasn't supplied all of the arguments that are present in its definition.

The function was defined here:

```
int sumRange(int lowerNumber, int higherNumber);
```

As you can see, there are two arguments in the definition: `int lowerNumber, int higherNumber`. But your use of that function here:

```
printf("\nThe sum number of all ranges for both numbers is: %d", sumRange(sum));
```

Only supplies that function with one argument. Since you are reading the arguments in with scanf, the correct use would be:

```
printf("\nThe sum number of all ranges for both numbers is: %d", sumRange(lowerNumber, higherNumber));
```